# d3.js appending different SVG elements based on a data value

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am working on an d3.js tree to display XML Schema elements in the tree based on their element type.

I have code like the following:

```
    // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
                    .attr('class', 'node')
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                          return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
                    })
                    .on('click', clickXSD)
                    .on('dblclick', dblclickXSD);

nodeEnter.append('rect')
         .filter(function(d) { return d.data.elementType == "xs:element" })
         .attr('class', 'node')
         .attr('y', -16)
         .attr('rx', 5)
         .attr('ry', 5)
         .attr('width', function(d) { return d.data.y_size + 50; })
         .attr('height', function(d) { return 32; })
         .style("fill", function(d) {
               return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "lemonchiffon";
         });
```

I would like to be able to make the code a little cleaner by implementing something like:

```
nodeEnter.xs-element()
         .filter(function(d) { return d.data.elementType == "xs:element" })
```

or something similar and then have a function to draw the xs:element and then one to draw the xs:attribute, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer here: https://www.atlassian.com/blog/archives/extending-d3-js.

There are two possible ways.  One is to make a prototype and the other is to use the call function.  I am using the second way.

```
    nodeEnter.filter(function(d) { return d.data.elementType == "xs:element" }).call(xsElement);

  function xsElement(selection) {
    selection.append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'node')
    .attr('y', -16)
    .attr('rx', 5)
    .attr('ry', 5)
    .attr('width', function(d) { 
    return d.data.y_size + 50;
    })
    .attr('height', function(d) { 
    return 32;
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
    return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "lemonchiffon";
    })
    .filter(function(d) { return d.data.documentation != null })
    .append("title").text(function(d) { return d.data.documentation; });

  // Add labels for the nodes
  selection.append('text')
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("y", -6)
  .attr("x", 6)
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

.
.
.

  }
```

Where selection is the value of the filtered nodeEnter.